# Why are throughput and latency inversely proportional on pub/sub systems?

Tags: rabbitmq, apache-kafka, publish-subscribe, latency, throughput

When reading [a paper](https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3093908) (not free) comparing Kafka and RabbitMQ, I came across the following (emphasis mine):

> Latency. In any transport architecture, latency of a packet/message is
>   determined by the serial pipeline (i.e., sequence of processing steps)
>   that it passes through. Latency can only be reduced by pipelining the packet transport over resources that can work concurrently on the same packet in a series architecture (multiple processing cores, master DMA engines in case of disk or network access,…) . **It is not infuenced by scaling out resources in
>   parallel.**
>
> Throughput. Throughput of a transport architecture is the number of
>   packets (or alternatively,bytes) per time unit that can be transported
>   between producers and consumers. Contrary to latency,throughput can
>   easily be enhanced by adding additional resources in parallel.
>
> **For a simple pipeline throughput and latency are inversely
>   proportional.**

Why is it so? Isn't that the contrary of saying that "(latency) is not influenced by scaling out resources in parallel"? If I add more machines to increase the throughput, how is the latency reduced?

Comment: You'd have to understand what they mean by "for a simple pipeline" - without that, we're left to assume.

Answer (score 3):

Let's examine the scenario of a highway, and for purposes of discussion we'll use I-66 in the Washington, DC metro. This highway experiences rush hour delays each morning amounting to about 40-60 minutes of additional travel time. This is because the *throughput* of the road is constrained.  As a result, latency for a single car increases.

The general theory behind this is known as [Little's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Little%27s_law). It states that the average amount of time a customer (or in this case, a driver) spends in a system (i.e. the highway) is equal to the arrival rate divided by total number of customers in the system.  Expressed algebraically,

[image: Little's Law]

The practical implications of this are that, given an increase in the number of cars `L`, such as what happens around rush hour, and given constant throughput of the highway `Lambda` (Virginia got a little creative and figured out how to dynamically convert a shoulder into a traffic lane, but it wasn't very effective), what results is an increase in the time it takes to travel a defined distance `W`.  The inverse of `W` is the speed of a car.

It is clear that, by Little's Law, throughput `lambda` is inversely proportional to latency (time) `W` for a constant number of cars `L`.